# How to get difference between two lists as transition sequence?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two lists:

```
First: "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
Second: "B", "C", "K", "L", "D"
```

I need to have transition from first to second like this:

```
remove "A" (at 0)
insert "K" (at 2)
insert "L" (at 3)
remove "E" (at 5)
```

Is there any good algorithm or complete library?

Comment: what does mean by transition?

Comment: sorry for my english. in this case - sequence of events how I can visualise the modification from first to second

Comment: how you will decide which list you need to take for insertion and deletion???

Comment: i don't understand question, sorry. i have start state (first list) and end state (second list). so i need modify first list by elementary operations to take second list.

Comment: This looks like Edit Distance problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance  
Take a look at it :D

Comment: @tse Can you see a situation where you could get more than one possible transition list?

Comment: Now i got you want to make first list similar to second one by doing these operations in first list??

Comment: @gilleain no problem, i'll take first :)

Answer (score 2):

To post this as an answer instead of as a comment.

This looks like Edit distance problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

There are already many tutorials/videos for this, but here are some:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocZMDMZwhCY
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-5-edit-distance/

Happy coding :D